# Error in getting Current User's SharePoint group

Tags: infopath, web-services

I am facing this issue while creating a data connection using web services.
My requirement was to get current user's SharePoint Group and i followed this link
    [Getting the Current User's SharePoint Group Name](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/getting-current-users-sharepoint-group.html)

I dont have access to check ULS viewer. But the form gives me the below error

> An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.
>
> Log ID:5566

Comment: you only require infopath or javascript is also an option?

Comment: yes javascript is also an option